# How to get 20k tweets in a specific language

Tags: twitter, twitter4j, tweets

I need to get more than 20 tweets in a specific language, around 1000 but using the following code I am getting just 15-20 tweets. can anyone help me?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setJSONStoreEnabled(true)
                .setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey("*********")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret("*******")
                .setOAuthAccessToken("********")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("****");

        TwitterFactory twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        twitter4j.Twitter twitterClient = twitterFactory.getInstance();
        final ResponseList<Status> homeTimelineStatuses = twitterClient.getHomeTimeline();

        for (final Status status : homeTimelineStatuses) {
            final String lang = status.getLang();
            final String rawText = status.getText();
            if (lang.equals("en")) {
                System.out.println("^^ " + rawText);
            } else {
                System.out.println("not en");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you [read the documentation for `home_timeline`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline) you will see that it says the number of tweet you can get...

> Defaults to 20. The value of count is best thought of as a limit to the number of tweets to return because suspended or deleted content is removed after the count has been applied.

If you want more than 20 Tweets, you can use the `count` parameter.

> Specifies the number of records to retrieve. Must be less than or equal to 200.

If you want to get *more* than 200 Tweets, you will need to understand Pagination.  I'm unfamiliar with Twitter4J - but [the documentation covers it in detail](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/TimelinesResources.html#getHomeTimeline-twitter4j.Paging-)